# Uploadify - uploadfolder curiosity

Tags: jquery, uploadify, var

i work with the JQuery Upload Plugin [Uploadify](http://uploadify.com)

you need to  define the upload folder for the plugin:

```
 'folder'            : /xyz/zxy,
```

So i generate the folderadress with javascript:

```
installFolder+'/'+activeDirectory.substr(0,activeDirectory.length-1)
```

If I use this the plugin with this adress the file will be uploaded to a folder I don't want.

The result of

```
installFolder+'/'+activeDirectory.substr(0,activeDirectory.length-1)
```

is exactly

```
/xyz/zxy
```

it doesn't work. BUT if a use

```
'folder' : /xyz/zxy
```

it works.

little bit confusing. any hints? :)

Comment: "to a folder I don't want." What folder does it try to upload?

Comment: it creates a new folder like httpdocsunspecified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using .uploadifySettings to change the value of the variable?
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifysettings/